# Relationship between NP and CoNP

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, reductions, np

I have a question from a test that I could not pass, I could not answer the question and I am looking for help with this question

This is the question

Will be $A\in \mathbf{NP}$

Suppose that $A\notin \mathbf{coNP}$. determine which of the claims is correct:

1. $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{coNP}$
2. $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{NP}$
3. $\mathbf{P}\neq \mathbf{NP}$
4. $\mathbf{NP} \cap \mathbf{coNP} = \varnothing $

According to the data in the question, you need to choose the correct answer from the 4 possible answers.

I do not understand if there is any connection at all between the language A, and the answers themselves.

What I think is that A must only be in $\mathbf{NP}$ and it cannot be in $\mathbf{P}$, because it is not in $\mathbf{coNP}$, and $\mathbf{coNP}$ itself is in $\mathbf{P}$.

But I do not find an answer that can fit it, maybe 3 is correct, but it has nothing to do with the question at all, it is always true.

Comment: it is incorrect to say that $coNP\subseteq P$. If this were true then $P=NP$, and we don't know that.

Comment: Thanks, if a problem is in $coNP$, it does not have to be in $P$ too? Or it can be but not necessarily.

Comment: Not necessarily. Its an open problem. Knowing whether $coNP\subseteq P$ or $coNP \neq P$ is equivalent to knowing whether $P=NP$ or $P\neq NP$.

Answer (score 1):

$P$ is closed under complement. The rest is up to you.

Comment: Thanks, if I understood you correctly, actually, P = COP, and by the question $A\in NP $ and $A\notin CoNP $, therefore $CoNP \neq NP$  and get that $CoP \neq P$ , but I do not see an answer to it

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is no. 3.

Suppose $A \in \text{NP}$ and $A \notin \text{co-NP}$. Clearly this shows $\text{NP} \neq \text{coNP}$, but that's not a possible choice for this question.

Observe that complement of the machine output can be trivially implemented in a deterministic polynomial machine. That is to say, $\text{P} = \text{co-P}$. Thus, if $\text{P} = \text{NP}$, then $P = \text{co-NP}$, which together imply $\text{NP} = \text{co-NP}$. This cannot be the case by assumption, so $\text{P} \neq \text{NP}$.

Answer (score -2):

1+2 are not proven true and false, considered to be extremely hard to be proven either way, and most people assume they are false. That obviously answers 3.

4: P is a subset of both NP and co-NP, and since P is not empty, 4 is false.

Language A is indeed irrelevant. If the question had said "assume A in co-NP" that would have shown much more trivially that 4 is false, but it's false anyway.

Comment: The language $A$ is not irrelevant. If there is a language $A\in NP$ but $A\not\in coNP$, as the question assumes, then it follows that $P\ne NP$, so 3 is the only correct statement of the four.